# Posting files to Google Classroom using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-classroom

I have been using the code below to post individual students' documents to a Google Classroom.

```
function postDoc(){ 
  const myCourseID = 24551294265;
  const myData = mySheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  myData.forEach(function(myRow, index){

  if(index === 0){return;}   

  const myGmail = myRow[0]; 
  const myDocId = myRow[14]; //assigns the pdf file ID     
    
  var myMaterial = {
      assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS",
      individualStudentsOptions: { studentIds: [myGmail] },
      title: "Report Document",
      materials: { driveFile: {driveFile:{id: myDocId}}}       
  };
  
  try{      
     const myNewReport = Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.create(myMaterial, myCourseID);       
  } 
  catch(err){    
     console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);      
  } 
 }); 
}
```

But, since last week, I am getting the following error message:

> API call to classroom.courses.courseWorkMaterials.create failed with error: Precondition check failed.

Comment: It would help if there was additional information from the error message. The documentation for this method (https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWorkMaterials/create) says a failed precondition can be caused by drive permission issues, among other things. See AttachmentNotVisible https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors#attachmentnotvisible. Consider double checking the permissions for the attached files.

Comment: Hello David, it is the only line of error I am getting. I am able to post the documents manually. So, it doesn't seem drive permission issue.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this by swapping in an invalid course ID. Can you try changing the course ID or ensure you have access to the course?